# Playing audio file from Firebase Storage works locally, but not on deployed appliation

Tags: reactjs, firebase, audio, firebase-storage

I've been working on a prototype of AAC application for a project. Basically you hit a button, it says a word (like a sound board). I'm using firebase to host it and firebase storage to store the files. It works locally off my computer, but when I go to the deployed application, the button presses do nothing. Is there something I'm missing here? The storage addresses are redacted and replaced with "BUCKET". The url has the bucket address as well as the token attached to them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { Card, Button, Alert, ButtonGroup } from "react-bootstrap"
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext"
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

export default function Dashboard() {
  const [error, setError] = useState("")
  const { currentUser, logout } = useAuth()
  const history = useHistory()

  let bpYes = new Audio("BUCKET")

  const pYes = () => {
    bpYes.play()
  }

  let bpNo = new Audio("BUCKET")

  const pNo = () => {
    bpNo.play()
  }

  let bpPlease = new Audio("BUCKET")

  const pPlease = () => {
    bpPlease.play()
  }

  let bpMore = new Audio("BUCKET")

  const pMore = () => {
    bpMore.play()
  }

  let bpEat = new Audio("BUCKET")

  const pEat = () => {
    bpEat.play()
  }

  let bpDrink = new Audio("BUCKET")

  const pDrink = () => {
    bpDrink.play()
  }

  let bpPlay = new Audio("BUCKET")

  const pPlay = () => {
    bpPlay.play()
  }

  let bpPotty = new Audio("BUCKET")

  const pPotty = () => {
    bpPotty.play()
  }
  
  async function handleLogout() {
    setError("")

    try {
      await logout()
      history.push("/login")
    } catch {
      setError("Failed to log out")
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="text-center">
        <h1>AAC PROTOTYPE</h1>
        <h2>Welcome!</h2>
      </div>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Profile</h2>
          {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
          <strong>Email:</strong> {currentUser.email}
          <Link to="/update-profile" className="btn btn-primary w-100 mt-3">
            Update Profile
          </Link>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <Card>
          <Card.Body>
            <ButtonGroup aria-label="Basic example" class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <Button size="lg" variant="outline-primary" onClick={pYes}>Yes</Button>
                <Button size="lg" variant="outline-primary" onClick={pNo}>No</Button>
                <Button size="lg" variant="outline-primary" onClick={pMore}>More</Button>
                <Button size="lg" variant="outline-primary" onClick={pPlease}>Please</Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
            <ButtonGroup aria-label="Basic example" class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <Button size="lg" variant="outline-primary"onClick={pEat}>Eat</Button>
                <Button size="lg" variant="outline-primary"onClick={pDrink}>Drink</Button>
                <Button size="lg" variant="outline-primary" onClick={pPlay}>Play</Button>
                <Button size="lg" variant="outline-primary" onClick={pPotty}>Potty</Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
          </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
        <Button variant="link" onClick={handleLogout}>
          Log Out
        </Button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: When you mean you played it locally, was that with direct access to the file, or was it loaded from storage?

Comment: It is loaded from storage. Meaning I’m running the application on my computer but it reaches out to storage.

Comment: I'm confused why it would work on one but not the other, that may indicate an additional issue

Answer (score 3):

Firebase doesn't support streaming audio files from storage, it works closer to a file download so a work around is needed.

Attached below is a common react script to play audio blobs from firebase storage and another for uploading.

**Download and play script**

```
const downloadAudio = async () => {
    const uri = await firebase
      .storage()
      .ref("nameOfTheFile.filetype")
      .getDownloadURL();

    console.log("uri:", uri);

    // The rest of this plays the audio
    const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
    try {
      await soundObject.loadAsync({ uri });
      await soundObject.playAsync();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error:", error);
    }
  };
```

**Upload as a data blob script**

```js
const uploadAudio = async () => {
    const uri = recording.getURI();
    try {
      const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = () => {
          try {
            resolve(xhr.response);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log("error:", error);
          }
        };
        xhr.onerror = (e) => {
          console.log(e);
          reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
        };
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
        xhr.send(null);
      });
      if (blob != null) {
        const uriParts = uri.split(".");
        const fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];
        firebase
          .storage()
          .ref()
          .child(`nameOfTheFile.${fileType}`)
          .put(blob, {
            contentType: `audio/${fileType}`,
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Sent!");
          })
          .catch((e) => console.log("error:", e));
      } else {
        console.log("erroor with blob");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error:", error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Ok so this might be a dumb question, but in my case I have 8 different files. I’m assuming this needs to be replicated 8 times then?

Comment: You would have to update the logic to load and return the values as needed, not repeat the code for each file. This can be done by passing values into the function itself `async (file)` and `uploadAudio(file)`

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you for your help. I’ll follow up after giving this a try!

Comment: How am I supposed to be importing storage in this instance? I have most of my firebase stuff in a different file, but really i want to get this working so I might just do it in the Dashboard file.

Comment: if you have a reference to FIrebase and you have the modules imported correctly, you can reference it from `firebase.storage()` otherwise web9: `import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";`

Comment: if it's all sorted, would you accept the answer? it'll help me out, thank you.